# Javascript AJAX Upload incompatible with Firefox

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox, xmlhttprequest

I use AJAX upload for my site, and Javascript is the choice (not jQuery).
But What I have come up with does not work with Firefox. Here is the XMLHttpRequest code block:

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open("POST", "upload.php");

    xhr.onprogress = function(event){
        if(event.lengthComputable)
        {
            console.log(event.loaded);
        }
    };

    xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

    xhr.send(formData);
```

And pay attention to `xhr.onprogress` event.

Alternatively, I also use the following code for progress:

```
xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(){
// do something
}, false);
```

But:

For the first solution which is `xhr.onprogress` it has a problem:

It just shows the amount of `event.loaded` after the upload has been finished. This amount is the same as the file size since the upload has fully loaded the file.
It works in both FF and chrome, but I don;t want it to just throw a value after the progress has reached to its end.

The second solution, though, is nice and works OK, but it in no way works in firefox. In firefox however, no error is thrown, and as I have tested, the `progressEvent` does not get triggered at all.

Both chrome and Firefox are of latest versions.

Answer (score 1):

I think problem is you add `onprogress` listener after `open()`, it should be done **before**:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onprogress = function (event) {
    if (event.lengthComputable) {
        console.log(event.loaded);
    }
};

xhr.open("POST", "upload.php");
```

Or:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.addEventListener("progress", function (event) {
    if (event.lengthComputable) {
        console.log(event.loaded);
    }
}, false);

xhr.open("POST", "upload.php");
```

Comment: none of them works. Even before open() it still sucks in firefox.

Comment: @MT-Developer Isn't length computable (size is unknown then event.lengthComputable === false) or progress event isn't fired at all?

Comment: the event is triggered at the end of the upload, so at the end, you see a number representing the event .loaded. While I expect to get a changing value right from the start to the end...

Comment: Yes, I mean: event itself is never triggered or lengthComputable is true only at the end (so you log to console only when finished)?

Comment: lengthComputable is true only at the end of the upload.

Comment: What's formData? An ArrayBufferView? Which version of FF?

Comment: FF 28.0. And formData, I have not applied any specific setting to it, just `new FormData()`; and regular `.append()`

Comment: There is a known bug about progress event on FF ([#786953](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=786953) or #908375 on OSX and Linux)), is it your case?

Comment: no I use Windows, though I have tested on Linux and it doesn't event gets triggered...

Comment: It's a regression, it's reported it didn't work on Windows too but I'm not sure because that issue is pretty old (so I don't know if it applies to current version or not).

Comment: You're not alone, kind of consolation...for FF you may setup a spinning icon

Comment: But I will come across a solution through server. Client side seems odd :)